# Swapping values of two variables

Tags: c#, variables, swap

I'm currently having a hard time swapping two variables. I'd like to be able swap values once the user enters a value which is next to a blank cell
Apologies for my extremely messy code, I'm just picking up C#.

```
static void SwapNums(string[,] theBoard)
    {
        int col, row;
        string swap;
        string number = ReadNumber();

        for (col = 0; col                 if (theBoard[col, row] == "")
                            {
                                theBoard[col, row] = number;

                            }
                        }
                    }                            

                }
            }
        }
    }
} < 6; col++)
        {
            for (row = 0; row < 6; row++)
            {
                if (theBoard[col,row] == number)
                {
                    if (theBoard[col + 1, row] == "-" || theBoard[col - 1, row] == "-" || theBoard[col, row + 1] == "" || theBoard[col, row - 1] == "-")
                    {
                        swap = theBoard[col, row];

                        theBoard[col, row] = "";

                        for (col = 0; col < 6; col++)
                        {
                            for (row = 0; row < 6; row++)
                            {
                                if (theBoard[col, row] == "")
                                {
                                    theBoard[col, row] = number;

                                }
                            }
                        }                            

                    }
                }                 if (theBoard[col, row] == "")
                            {
                                theBoard[col, row] = number;

                            }
                        }
                    }                            

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
            }
        }
    }
```

At the moment, this code is replacing the blank cellwith what the user entered, but is not replacing the cell that contains the number to p.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Your example has 5 columns, in your code you have 7. Hat should happen if user enters "3"?

Comment: Some tips: First do it on paper, by hand, observe what you are doing. Then think about code, variables, structure, algorithm. Then code it. Then use debugger to see what your code actually does.

Comment: The nested for loops inside the inside the if statement are not needed.

Comment: @DrKoch Sorry, the example to show what it would look like. If the user entered 3, nothing would happen, as that number is not next to a "-".

Comment: The if (theBoard[col + 1, row] == "-" || theBoard[col - 1, row] == "-" || theBoard[col, row + 1] == "-" || theBoard[col, row - 1] == "-")  tells you which cell contains "-", but putting all of the logical checks together obscures which cell it is.

Comment: @user3444160 Are they not? Because I only want the variables to swap if the user entered number is next to a -

Comment: @user3444160 How could I tell which cell it is?

Comment: if theBoard[col + 1, row] == "-" is true, you know the cell to swap.  The same is true for each logical statement.

Comment: also this theBoard[col - 1, row] will throw an index out of range exception when col is zero and the same is true for theBoard[col, row - 1] when row is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that gets the "position" of an element. Something like this?

```
const int ROWS = 6;
const int COLUMNS = 6;

static Tuple<int, int> GetPosition(string[,] theBoard, string value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
            if (theBoard[i, j] == value)
                return new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);

    return new Tuple<int, int>(-1, -1);
}
```

Then, just swap the elements, something like this:

```
var numberPosition = GetPosition(theBoard, number);
var minusPosition = GetPosition(theBoard, "-");

theBoard[numberPosition.Item1, numberPosition.Item2] = "-";
theBoard[minusPosition.Item1, minusPosition.Item2] = number;
```

Make sure to check if the element was found! (`Item1` and `Item2` will be `-1` if not)

Here you go, complete code that illustrates the concept: http://pastebin.com/5kjDPeX8

### Edit:

Oh yeah, it should be only swapped if the element is next to it, so then, just do a check on the returned positions. Here is a replacement for the `SwapNums` method: (I didn't update the pastebin code above)

```
static void SwapNums(string[,] theBoard, string number)
{
    var numberPosition = GetPosition(theBoard, number);
    var minusPosition = GetPosition(theBoard, "-");

    if (numberPosition.Item1 == -1 || minusPosition.Item1 == -1)
        throw new Exception("Element " + number + " or - was not found in theBoard!");

    if (numberPosition.Item1 == minusPosition.Item1) //they are in the same row
    {
        if (numberPosition.Item2 + 1 == minusPosition.Item2 ||
            numberPosition.Item2 - 1 == minusPosition.Item2) // if they are next to eachother
        {
            theBoard[numberPosition.Item1, numberPosition.Item2] = "-";
            theBoard[minusPosition.Item1, minusPosition.Item2] = number;
        }
    }
    else if (numberPosition.Item2 == minusPosition.Item2) // same column
    {
        if (numberPosition.Item1 + 1 == minusPosition.Item1 ||
            numberPosition.Item1 - 1 == minusPosition.Item1) //if they are above or below
        {
            theBoard[numberPosition.Item1, numberPosition.Item2] = "-";
            theBoard[minusPosition.Item1, minusPosition.Item2] = number;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### A slight digression (might be educational):

That `Tuple<int, int>` thing is just a class that contains two elements (namely `int Item1` and `int Item2`), which is really convenient to use when your function needs to return two things (in our case, the row and column position of the element).

The `<int, int>` part means that the types of `Item1` and `Item2` will be `int`. The `<something something etc.>` things on classes generally are a part of something called [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx), which is an advanced programming concept.

In short (about generics), it allows you to create a 'general' kind of an object, which could manipulate different types of object. `Tuple` here can contain pairs of any type of object; `Tuple<string, int>` would have `string Item1` and `int Item2`.

But this isn't something you should worry about right now. When you've made a few classes of your own, you'll understand why this is convenient. For now, the `Tuple` class is the thing when you need to return 2 somethings from a function quick and easy.

Comment: @Viroe hey, there is an update... I should start reading questions :)